# DownloadManger for Android 2.2

Tags: android, download-manager, android-2.2-froyo

Android offer a [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) from API 9 onwards and documentation says

> The download manager will conduct the download in the background,
>   taking care of HTTP interactions and **retrying downloads after failures
>   or across connectivity changes and system reboots**.

Around 4% of devices (04-Apr-2013) run [Android 2.2](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform) (API 8) so is there any library or backport of DownloadManager which can **retrying downloads after failures or across connectivity changes and system reboots** for Android 2.2.

Comment: There comes a point in time at which you really need to give up on old OSes to move things forward.  Only 4% of devices run Android 2.2.  How much time is it going to take to support it?  How many additional sales/downloads will you need to get it to break even?  I doubt its worth your time.

Comment: Agreed. Exploring the community if some work has been done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately NO. For Android 2.2 and below, you will have to code up your own download manager and handle all the things yourself. In fact many applications supporting FroYo have done a good job with this, so no need to re-invent the wheel. Just take pointers from SO and get coding!

Comment: All I can see on SO is something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog. These samples dont even come close of retrying in ConnectTimeout leave alone connectivity failure or system reboot.

Comment: Well, you need to dig up a bit more. Google a bit, there are good working samples which I have used myself too.